# How do I create a mocked and a non-mocked instance of a single class within one test method?

Tags: java, junit, jmockit

How do I create a mocked and a non-mocked instance of a single class within one test method?

An "Entry" can be expired, if its "lastContact" attribute is older than 5 minutes. I use a Mock to create such an Entry-object:

```
@Test
public void entryOlderThanFiveMinutesIsExpired() {

    new MockUp<Entry>() {
        @Mock
        public Date getLastContact() {
            return new Date(10000L); // date in the past
        }
    };
    Entry expiredEntry = new Entry();
    assertThat(expiredEntry.isExpired(), is(true));
}
```

This works fine.
In the next test, I need an "expired" and a non-"expired" entry (both will be added to an EntryList and after a "purge()" only the non-expired entry should remain).
But setting up mocks changes the whole class, so all instances of that class will be mocked:

```
@Test
public void test() {

    Entry unexpiredEntry = new Entry(); // this should not be mocked

    new MockUp<Entry>() {
        @Mock(invocations = 1)
        public Date getLastContact() {
            return new Date(10000L); // date in the past
        }
    };
    Entry expiredEntry = new Entry();
    assertThat(expiredEntry.isExpired(), is(true));
    assertThat(unexpiredEntry.isExpired(), is(false));
}
```

This fails. I tried several ways of setting up mocks, but I did'nt get it. 
How can I solve this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by adding a `mockit.Invocation` parameter and making the mock method `reentrant`. But it is simpler with the Expectations API, where you can declare an "`@Injectable Entry expiredEntry`" mock field/parameter which will not affect other instances of `Entry`.